# How to create dynamic fields in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, field

I am going to create a content type with daynamic fields, How to do it?

for example when user clicked on **add image button** can add some more images.

Comment: You need only the images are dynamic? You can use infinite values of images for example.

Answer (score 0):

if one field, or some of fields are not in a same group, Just select Unlimited value from (manage field -> edit -> values number --> select Unlimited (infinite))

else

If you need to add more of field, or group of field, then you need to use a field collection module [View Moudle From Here](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)

To use this module (after install & enable)->

Go to content type -> add field (field collection) and select its embedded -> then press add field -> save

after this, go to structure, field collection setting, you weill find your field, click on it, and add any filed you need to display when you add a content type ...

good luck